# How to create new group for products in drupal commerce?

Tags: 7, commerce

I am using the [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) module (in Drupal 7) for products.

I need to create different-different group like phone and shirts. And need to add parameters for phones.

Also I need variation by using taxonomy.

Please refer to the image below for more details:

[image]

Some more details:

- I am using 2 attributes: **Color** and **Memory**, implemented as taxonomies (vocabularies). But they are not showing as a select list on the cart page.
- **Color** is a vocabulary, with terms in it like black, silver and red.
- I added Color on product type fields and checked 'attribute option'.
- But still this widget not showing up on the cart page (it's only showing the selected value).

Or to phrase it in yet another way: I need attribute on cart page. I have added attribute by using taxonomy, but it's giving me only a link. Which means that when I select 'black', then it only shows 'black color' on the cart page (it does not show a 'select option').

Comment: I've integrated one of your comments in the question (which is where it belongs I think). And slightly corrected the grammar. Please double check to ensure I did correctly do so, and further refine (edit) where needed. Also, please refine edit that "different-different" phrasing, which I really don't understand (I'm probably not the only one ...).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to create a new product type (since you want to add "parameters", which I assume are "fields") :

```
/admin/commerce/products/types/add
```

Then add fields to your new product type (picture, size, screen resolution for phones...), choose chich fields will be used as attributes (like size for shirts), then create products using this new product type, then create a new product display (which is a regular node with a multiple product reference field) for this product type and reference your products with the product reference field on the product display. You can also use an existing product display to display all your types of product (in this case you have to allow the product display's product reference field to reference products of the new product type first).

Note that if you have several attribute fields, you need to create as many products as there is possible combinations. Say you have 3 sizes (S, M, L) and 2 colors (red, blue), you need to create 6 products :

- S blue
- S red
- M blue
- M red
- L blue
- L red

You may consider using [Commerce Product Option](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_option) or similar module for your use case.

It can be confusing at first, but the Drupal Commerce way of dealing with products is really effective.

Good luck

**EDIT**

To make a field act as an attribute on your add to cart form (i.e shirt sizes : a drop down with XS, S...), you need to define a field on your product type (see my URL), then on the manage field form (admin/commerce/products/types/your_product_type_machine_name/fields/your_field_machine_name), you need to check the checkbox "Enable this field to function as an attribute field on Add to Cart forms".

Then you create your product, one with size S, one with size M, one with size L (so you have 3 products, one per size), on your product display you set up references to the 3 product variations (S, M, L), and there it is, on your product display page you'll find a drop down allowing to choose the size in the add to cart form. When selecting a size, the node fields are refreshed with AJAX (you can see it as an AJAX product selector).

This system allows you to have different SKUs and prices for each variations. Typically, everything that needs to be different across products variations (SKU obviously, but maybe price, maybe the product picture) needs to be represented by a field on the *product* (each product has its own field value). Everything that is the same across product variations can be represented by a field on the *product display* (which is common to several products.

See [here](https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/product-attributes-variations) for official doc.

Hope it helps and sorry for my english, not my first language.

Comment: Managing products (and orders) can indeed be a bit confusing, however, Commerce Backoffice (https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_backoffice) helps with that in a good way (especially the auto creation of product display nodes).

Comment: @Watergate Never tried that, I'll check it out thanks !

Comment: thanks.. I am using 2 attribute color and memory by using taxonomy vocabs. but its not showing as a select list on cart page.

Comment: If you use Commerce Backoffice, you most probably also want to use the Shiny administration theme: https://www.drupal.org/project/shiny

Comment: @Flo I followed your step. but still I am not getting dropdown on product page.

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1 - Use Commerce Backoffice

As mentioned also in one of the comments, managing products (and orders) can be confusing. However, the [Commerce Backoffice](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_backoffice) module helps with that. Especially because of the ***auto creation of product display nodes***.

So consider using the Commerce Backoffice module. It provides the backoffice functionality present in [Commerce Kickstart (V2)](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart). It contains these sub-modules:

- Commerce Backoffice **Product** (commerce_backoffice_product).
- Commerce Backoffice **Order** (commerce_backoffice_order).
- Commerce Backoffice **Content** (commerce_backoffice_content).

This module (and a few dependencies) provides the rich store owner experience that has made Commerce Kickstart 2 so popular (and prevents that you have to install the entire Commerce Kickstart distribution). And there is a [great video introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkMZ_VcBan0) about it also.

**Note** (as suggested in a comment here also): if you use [Commerce Backoffice](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_backoffice), you most probably also want to use the [Shiny](https://www.drupal.org/project/shiny) administration theme, also used in [Commerce Kickstart (V2)](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart).

## Option 2 - Roll your own cookies

If you're ready to possible get confused, and/or don't mind all the required effort (if you have a lot of "attributes" to configure), then you may want to go over the various steps as explained in [these 5 videos](http://codekarate.com/category/series/drupal-commerce-series).

Comment: Please see above image. I need attribute on cart page,, I have added attribute by using taxonomy .. but its giving me only link.. means when I select black then it only show black color on cart page not show select option.

Comment: @jsh Edited my answer. So Memory, Color, Provider and Contract must be product fields, and you'll have to create as many products as there is possible combinations for these fields values (16Go/red, 16Go/blue, 32Go/red and so on...can be a lot with 4 attributes fields...). Quantity is managed by Drupal Commerce.

Comment: If you use Commerce Backoffice, you most probably also want to use the Shiny administration theme: https://www.drupal.org/project/shiny

Comment: color is a vocab and black,silver and red. are term. And I added color on product type fileds with checked attribue option...but still this widget not showing on cart page.its only show selected value.

Comment: It gives me
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0fc5212696

Comment: @jsh So you are using a term reference field as a product attribute, this page describes the steps : https://drupalcommerce.org/commerce-kickstart-2/adding-taxonomy-field-product-attributes. But if you checked the magical checkbox it should work anyway...flush the cache :) ? Are you sure you addded your term reference field to the product type and not the product display ?

Comment: @Flo please check screenshot. I did this http://awesomescreenshot.com/007521co8c
http://awesomescreenshot.com/00a521cx67

Comment: @jsh Did you create product variations, i.e several products with different values for your term reference field ? Not sure how DC behave when there is only one product (so there is no need for a drop down)

Comment: @Flo Yes I created 2 product one with color - black..second with color-silver.

Comment: Did you reference the 2 products with the product reference field on the product display node ?